# why is this piece of code able to tell if a number in a 2D array has been repeated?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, 2d

```
//checking validity of sudoku solution
bool validityCheck (int sudoku [25][25], int n, int sqrt_n) {
     //checking rows validity
     for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { // i means place in column
        bool numCounter [25] = { false };
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++){  //j means place in row
            if (numCounter[(sudoku[i][j])-1] == true){
                return false;
             }
            else {
                numCounter[(sudoku[i][j]) -1] = true;
            }
        }
     }
     //checking columns validity
     for (int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
        bool numCounter [25] = {false};
        for (int  i = 0; i<n; ++i){
            if (numCounter[sudoku[i][j]-1] == true){
                return false;
             }
            else {
                numCounter[sudoku[i][j]-1]=true;
            }
        }
    }
    //checking square validity
    for (int s = 0; s < sqrt_n; s++) { //s means square in column
        for (int r = 0; r < sqrt_n; r++) {//r means square in row
            bool numCounter [25] = {false};
            int j = sqrt_n * s;
            for ( ; j < sqrt_n; ++j) {
                int  i = sqrt_n * r;
                for ( ; i < sqrt_n; ++i){
                    if (numCounter[sudoku[i][j]-1] == true){
                        return false;
                     }
                    else {
                        numCounter[sudoku[i][j]-1]=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Hello guys, this piece of code uses bool to tell if a number has been repeated in rows, columns, or square roots of a 2D array.
is it that at first the bool is set to false, if let's say the value 4 is repeated, then at first it becomes true then it gets checked again and is found to be true, so we know it has been repeated and return false?
i think i got it, just making sure.

Comment: `bool numCounter [25] = { false };` is the same as setting all 25 items to zero, and zero is the same thing as `false` in this case.

Comment: Yes you have it. It would be more elegant to only pass in the linear dimension "sqrt_n" of the puzzle subsquare as N and also check that it isn't more than 5. Main square size N^2 is derivable and it reduces the risk of user error. It would be more elegant and compact to use bitset rather than an array of bool. But the logic is clear first occurrence of a digit sets numCounter[digit] to true or quits with a fail result if it is already true - it would be better named seenDigit (or truly count them).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it has a checklist with all the numbers from 1 to 26, checks if the number has been used, and if not it writes it.

So, numCounter is an array of 25 bools, as there are only 25 number per row (1 to 26).
Each bool in the array indicates if the number at index has been used.
So the lines

```
if (numCounter[(sudoku[i][j])-1] == true){
            return false;
         }
        else {
            numCounter[(sudoku[i][j]) -1] = true;
        }
```

First check whether the number has been used, if it has, it returns the function with a false, meaning that the sudoku is not correct; and if not, it sets it as used by putting the bool in true.
In this case, the line

```
sudoku[i][j]
```

Returns the number in the array sudoku, in the actual column(i) in the actual row position (j). That should give you a number between 1 and 26. Then you put the -1 because arrays start at 0 instead of 1.